# Reporting Services | Stop Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, cache-control

got a really fun one from my boss today. We have an asp website which uses a Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer component and everything is lovely. However if the browser (currently testing with IE9) is set up to always use cached pages (Tools->Internet Options->General Tab->Browsing History->Settings->Check for newer versions of stored pages->Never) then, for some god forsaken reason, the browser always uses the cached report. Microsoft huh, what can you do with them.

To be clear, the reports have some parameters which are entered by the user and it runs correctly the first time. If the user then changes the parameters and clicks view report again the screen flickers and does everything to appear as if it is generating a new report but the same report is displayed (i.e. the original parameters are used again to generate the report rather than the new ones). The text boxes into which the parameters are entered (part of the rdl) hold the correct values, it is just the report itself which doesn't update them.

I've tried adding the following javascript to the page which hosts the reportviewer control:

```
    <%
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.Expires = 0; 
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    %>
```

and the following c# to the hosting page's page_load function:

```
        this.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        this.Response.Expires = 0;
        this.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        this.Response.AddHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        this.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "private");
        this.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

without success. Does anyone know how to force the browser to update despite the browser history setting?

Comment: The real question is who in their right mind would use `Check for newer versions of stored pages->Never`

Answer (score 3):

Adding "rs:ClearSession=true" to a query helped me.
Taken from [here](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2005/10/05/disabling-the-sql-reporting-services-cache/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a GET to generate the report, all you have to do is make the URL unique. I usually do this by using `DateTime.Now.Ticks`

So when you change the parameters, just add an extra parameter to the query string(in theory, should work with POST as well). Something like `url+="&timestamp="+DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: I'm not using GET or POST. The first time the report is called it uses the report viewers refresh() method but after that I'm pressing view report button within the report view control and it doesn't go through my code at all...